# Entity Framework How to Add "Image" to database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using asp.net 4.0 and Mvc3 utilizing the entity modeler. How do I create an entry that is an image?

For example, I want the user to upload an image and then save it in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not different from when using pure ado.net.
Just decide whether save image into hard disk with path in the database, or blob in the database

Comment: but when modeling you have to give it a type, and there is not a blob type..?

Comment: just choose the "Binary Type"